# Non-relative NSArray sort

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsstring

I want to sort an NSArray of NSStrings by similarity to a single given string, as opposed to relative sort order for items within the array.

Or to put it a different way, I want to sort the array by comparing all the items contained in the array by similarity to a single item, not sort them by comparing each other.

I have the logic for similarity figured out, it's just how I use the NSArray and/or NSSortDescriptor APIs to achieve this.

Comment: Consult the spec for NSArray.  There are sort methods that accept a generic function or selector, so you can embed any logic you desire.

Comment: I've been looking at `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:]` however this still seems to be about comparing two objects using an outside parameter. What I want is sorting based on a single object and one outside parameter.

Comment: @AndrewEbling is there a criteria for "similarity"?

Comment: You can only sort two objects relative to each other.  Sorting an object without another object to compare to is meaningless.  What you *can* do is come up with a formula for "distance" from your "single item", and sort objects based on their relative distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortedArrayUsingComparator` should allow you to achieve this ...

```
NSArray* sourceArray = //... your data
NSString* itemToCompareTo = sourceArray[5]; // locate the item you want to compare to

NSArray* sortedArray = [listItem sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    // compare a, b, and itemToCompareTo here, using your sort logic
}
```

Comment: `itemToCompareTo` may or may not be in the array to sort. However I've realised if I compute the "distance" of both `id a` and `id b` to `itemToCompareTo` and return the appropriate value from the comparator, I get the desired result. Accepting as the answer, in recognition of the inspiration which got me to the solution :)